# MAUI app under Android hot to give write permission to BlazorWebView

Tags: android, maui-blazor

I'm developing a MAUI Blazor app that should run under windows and android

On Android I get an error from a component that tries to write on the clipboard

blazor.webview.js:1 Write permission denied.

Reading [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#-configuration) I cannot figure out where and how to call the BlazorWebViewInizializing event to allow this permission

Or should I do something also in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can check document [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android).

In android, `Permission`s must have the matching attributes set in the Android `Manifest` file. Permission status defaults to `Denied`.

Above article describes how you can use the .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) `Permissions` class. This class allows you to check and request permissions at run-time. The `Permissions` type is available in the `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel` namespace.

**Checking permissions**:

To check the current status of a permission, use the `Permissions.CheckStatusAsync` method along with the specific permission to get the status for. The following example checks the status of the `LocationWhenInUse` permission:

```
 PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

**Requesting permissions**:

To request a permission from the users, use the `Permissions.RequestAsync` method along with the specific permission to request. If the user previously granted permission, and hasn't revoked it, then this method will return `Granted` without showing a dialog to the user. The following example requests the `LocationWhenInUse` permission:

```
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

For more information, you can check document [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android).